# Closing window is not enough to close the application on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac

I'm new to Mac OS X and noticed something odd. Sometimes, closing the main window of an application is not enough to close the application. The process is still there, running.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: As an alternative solution, I usually bring up a terminal. Type xkill, and then click the application. Never have had a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed it is.  Coming from Windows this is one of the first things one notices about Mac operating systems.  Thankfully, there are many other ways to close a running application, including File > Quit on the application's menu and Command-Q.

Comment: Especially with the many applications that can do useful stuff in the background (feed readers, mail clients, instant messengers, download managers or bit torrent clients, iTunes) or when you don't want to repeat the the application initialization over and over (task management, text editors, iCal) this behavior makes a lot of sense.

You will also notice that also many applications DO close when their last window was closed (games come to mind, but there are others).

Answer (score 2):

it happen for almost all apllication if you want close it completely use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

This image shows the dock - the little lights below Mail.app, Safari.app and iCal.app indicate that the application is open, even if no windows are open.  As you can see from the contextual menus in the image, right clicking (or Ctrl-click) gives you a menu that you can use to close an open application.

Otherwise the previously mentioned command-Q is understood as the universal quit command too - just be sure you are in the application you intend to quit before pressing the keystroke!

JDB

[image: Mac OS X 10.6 Dock]