# Remove Dock of apps no longer using a window, but still running

Tags: macos, dock

How can I keep the OS X Dock clean of unused apps? Let's say I open an image with Xee. After closing the window, Xee's icon is still shown in the dock.

Is there a chance to see only the icons of apps in the dock, which are used or kept (when 'Keep in Dock' is active)?

I've [seen a question on closing the entire app after the last window](https://superuser.com/questions/53935/getting-mac-os-x-applications-to-close-after-last-window-closed) is closed, but that doesn't address wanting to keep the app open, just that I don't want it showing in the Dock.

Comment: Why don't you quit the whole application with Cmd+Q?

Comment: Starting a app completely new costs more performance, I guess. I see advantages in the design principle of OSX, but not in terms of the dock's "behaviour"..

Comment: It's in the dock because it's still running http://superuser.com/questions/181549/closing-window-is-not-enough-to-close-the-application-on-mac-os-x/ . How much performance cost have you measured for each restart of the app?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, I did not measure the loading times. It's just the 1-2 sec. delay I recognize when I start a app which isn't in the cache.. but your right: it's not a deal breaker :)